# AttributeError in creating module

Tags: pytorch

I am getting the following error.

> AttributeError: cannot assign module before Module.**init**() call

I have a class as follows.

```
class Classifier(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, dictionary, embeddings_index, max_seq_length, args):  
        self.embedding = EmbeddingLayer(len(dictionary), args.emsize, args.dropout)
        self.drop = nn.Dropout(args.dropout)
```

What I am doing wrong here? I am beginner in PyTorch, please help!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should always do when you create a module is call its super constructor. So, your class should look like this:

```
class Classifier(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, dictionary, embeddings_index, max_seq_length, args): 
        super(Classifier, self).__init__() 
        '''Rest of your code goes here.'''
```